# Changes in compiz don't affect Unity

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10, and added Compiz (which wasn't there by default).

I've noticed, that all changes I make in Unity Plugin (launchpad behavior, icos size, transparency) don't affect Unity at all - it is just as it was after being installed.

The changes are stored (when I open the settings again all my changes are set), they just don't appear on the screen :)

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are logging into a unity-2d session which doesn't use compiz.
Several possible reasons -

You are picking Unity-2d at the login instead of Ubuntu

Your hardware or current video drivers don't support 3d so you're falling back to unity-2d. To check run this in a terminal

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

After checking the above you'll have a better idea of how to proceed

Comment: doug, you're right - no unity 3d support.
I've found a simple GUI program to unhide launchpad, but is there a way to make launch icons smaller?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too when I try to change Unity in ccsm. I've solved with just a reboot. Try it.